# Refresh services when AppConfiguration values are refreshed in Azure Isolated Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-app-configuration

I am following the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process) to refresh the App Config values when any config value is changed. However is there a way to refresh the services such as HTTPClient that are injected similar to the below where baseUrl is fetched from app config -

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GitHub", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(appConfig.BaseUrl!);

    // using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
    // The GitHub API requires two headers.
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.Accept, "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
        HeaderNames.UserAgent, "HttpRequestsSample");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by registering a callback on configuration refresh like this.

```
      refreshOptions.NotifyOnRefresh(async () =>
            {
            // Update the properties of the injected HTTPClient service 
        var httpClient = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("GitHub");                                

httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(appConfig.BaseUrl!);
            });
```